# Docker volume access from host

Tags: docker

I have a docker file that looks like this. How can I access this volume from the host? I checked the volumes folder where Docker is installed.

```
FROM busybox

MAINTAINER Erik Kaareng-sunde <esu@enonic.com>

RUN mkdir -p /enonic-xp/home
RUN adduser -h /enonic-xp/ -H -u 1337 -D -s /bin/sh enonic-xp
RUN chown -R enonic-xp /enonic-xp/
VOLUME /enonic-xp/home
ADD logo.txt /logo.txt
CMD cat /logo.txt
```

ls

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               b4e99290fd4d5f7a3fe700ae9b616c2e66b1f758c497662415cdb47905427719
```

I would like to be able to cd into that volume.

```
inspect
docker volume inspect b4e99290fd4d5f7a3fe700ae9b616c2e66b1f758c497662415cdb47905427719
[
    {
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/b4e99290fd4d5f7a3fe700ae9b616c2e66b1f758c497662415cdb47905427719/_data",
        "Name": "b4e99290fd4d5f7a3fe700ae9b616c2e66b1f758c497662415cdb47905427719",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you doing it from dockerfile in purpose? Did you consider to add the volume mounting when running the container?

Comment: I want to move files from outside into the volume.

Comment: How did you run the container? With 'docker run ..'?

Comment: How is Docker installed? If it is Docker Machine, Docker Toolbox, or Docker for Windows or Mac, then you will have an intermediary virtual machine and the files will actually be living on that VM.

Comment: Here its on mac but I am also interested to know how it works on normal linux. I think its the whole toolbox

Answer (score 4):

After looking at a lot of posts, I finally found a post that address the question asked here.

[Getting path and accessing persistent volumes in Docker for Mac](https://timonweb.com/posts/getting-path-and-accessing-persistent-volumes-in-docker-for-mac/)

Note: this works only for Mac.

The path for the `tty` may also be present here:

> ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vm/*/tty

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing it within the dockerfile, you can simply mount with `docker run -v /path/in/host:/path/in/container image-name....`

Comment: thanks but I need the dockerfile approach because thats whats in the documentation http://xp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getstarted/docker.html.

Comment: @itayb follow up question. whats the syntax for then there's many mount points in the image? I'm specifically working with https://hub.docker.com/r/wonderfall/boring-nginx/

Comment: The mount points are to the container, and you can simply concat more than one volume

Answer (score 0):

Docker volume ls lists all volumes docker volume inspect lets you inspect a volume. If you cant find your volume with docker volume ls try docker inspect your container and check for info there

Comment: Docker volume inspect the volume that docker ls listed an somewhere in the output you will find enonic-xp/home and close by (as mount or something like that) the path on your machine

Comment: var/lib/docker does not exist

Comment: Permission problem use sudo

Comment: I thinks that volumen exist on my vm because I am on mac.